# how to solve Dirac Equation numerically?

Tags: matrices, operator-theory

The effective Hamiltonian for my system is:
\begin{equation}
H=\nu_{F} {\bf \sigma}\cdot\left(q-By\hat x\right)
\end{equation}
where ${\bf \sigma}$ and $q$ are the Pauli matrices and the momentum operator respectively and $\nu_{F}$ is a constant. I would like to solve the Dirac equation numerically for the given Hamiltonian. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Since this is the Mathematics Stack Exchange rather than the Physics Stack Exchange, it would be helpful if you could specify the problem in a way more familiar to mathematicians. Some places to start: what are the other four variables ($\nu_F,x,y,B$) you haven't named? What are the basic properties (or just the definition) of the relevant quantities? Most importantly, which variable do you want to solve the equation for?

Comment: @Ian $\nu_{F}$ and $B$ are constants where as $x,y$ are coordinates.

Comment: @Ian I posted in the Physics Stack Exchange.